# Find owner of Android Wear watch

Tags: lost-phone, android-wear

Today I found an LG Watch R W110 while hiking. It's not screen locked, so I've poked around to try and identify the owner. There's only one number in the call log (other entries are all names) and I called it but it was a business that couldn't narrow down the search.

I thought I might be able to pair it with my own phone and redial "Mum" from the call log, but couldn't get it to pair with my iPhone. If I were to pair it with an Android phone, would doing so wipe the existing call log, or might I then be able to call "Mum"?

If not, is there any other way to find information about the watch's owner?

Comment: The Hangouts app may have some information. Pairing with a new phone will wipe the watch.

Comment: You can also try connecting the watch to WiFi, and then send a Hangout message to "Mum".

Comment: Can you long-press on the name to see more details? (I have no real idea how these watches work.)

Comment: You probably should also find out what you're legally or customarily supposed to do with lost property (e.g., maybe you're supposed to turn it in to the local police station, or a lost-and-found at the park). That's probably also who the owner would contact if he/she is looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following apps:

Google, Hangouts, Agenda, Messenger. I was browsing through my Moto 360 and those had some infomation.